# Map area size and position issues on different screen resolutions

Tags: html, dictionary, containers, resolution, css

I have a map area over a JPEG that i'm using for my navigation bar that has links to my different web pages:

```
<div id="container">
<img src="home.jpg" usemap="#imagemap" id="main-nav" style="max-width:100%;" />
<map name="imagemap">
<area shape="circle" coords="93,225,83" href="home.html" id="home">
<area shape="circle" coords="287,226,83" href="about.html" id="about"/>
<area shape="circle" coords="685,224,84" href="gallery.html" id="gallery" />
<area shape="circle" coords="876,226,87" href="facilities.html" id="facilities"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="-2,-8,1095,106" href="home.html" />
</map>
</div>
```

In order for my navigation image to fit my "container" div (width 75%), i have set the max-width to 100% (which does what I want it to), but this is an issue as when I load my site on different resolutions, the map areas are out of place and size.

Are there any ways around it? preferably a solution that would work in IE7+ but anything would be good.

Cheers!

Comment: I think it is not the best idea to do navigation bar with single image and area mapping. Why won't you slice it, place it tha way you want and put every image in `a` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to slice home.jpg to 5 parts or use jQuery to set proper coordinates of your areas depending of website width.

for example

```
var winWidht = $(window).width(); //detect widht of window
$('#home').attr('coords',winWidth/5 + ',' + 225 + ',' + winWidth/6); //set coord X and radius of your circle
```

it's just for example, create your basic math modifications, you have to llbit play with it :)
you can set other coords by replacing home